# Tajo: how update (from S3) is triggered?

Tags: analytics, apache-tajo

I set up a Tajo table from a S3 path and my understanding is that any changes in the S3 will be automatically applied to the Tajo table. Does Tajo poll status of the S3 object and see whether there is any change? How does that work in more detail? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user submits a SQL query to Tajo cluster running on Amazon EC2 and S3, Tajo directly reads and processes dataset stored in Amazon S3. So, latest queries always read updated data set on Amazon S3. You don't need to concern about how to update Tajo tables on updating objects in Amazon S3.